# jquery-rails and jquery-ui-rails gems not working as expected in Ruby on Rails application

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm having issues with the `jquery-rails` and `jquery-ui-rails gems`.  I have gotten to the point where, locally, I can get datepickers to **show up** and certain effects to work.  However, when I check the site being hosted on heroku, even my rails ajax responses are not working.  They default to the regular html responses in the controllers with an error that reads

```
Error: Sprockets::FileNotFound: couldn't find file 'jquery' (in /app/app/assets/javascripts/application.js:4)
```

I've noticed that it says `/app/app/` which I know is not right, but I'm not sure how to fix this.

Here is what's included in my application.js:

```
//= require_self
//= require foundation.min
//= require app
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
```

### Question 1:

When I add the `jquery-rails` and `jquery-ui-rails` gems in my Gemfile, should those be included in my `group :assets do` block, or should they be outside?  I have tried both and it doesn't work either way, but I figured there was a correct answer to this question assuming I get everything else working correctly.

Also, I have read everywhere that the `jquery-ui-rails` gem includes the css I need for things like the jquery datepicker, but the only way I can get the datepicker to have any styling whatsoever is to include the code url in my application.html.erb file.

### Question 2:

Should I be able to add a datepicker to a form that is loaded in a partial via built in rails ajax responses (*.js.erb)?  I have a list of partials that have a datepicker for a particular text_field, but when I click on a date (local side), the date is not placed in the text_field.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer 1:**
The :assets group basically acts as a shortcut for other groups based on what you set in your config/application.rb file:

```
if defined?(Bundler)
 # If you precompile assets before deploying to production, use this line
 # Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test staging)))
 # If you want your assets lazily compiled in production, use this line
 Bundler.require(:default, :assets, Rails.env)
end
```

Whether or not this is nifty or required in your project is up to you, really. I usually always take them out of the :assets group, but it's just 'cause I group a bit different and like my Gemfile tidy.

**As for the css-files**, do `*= require jquery-ui/jquery-ui.css`

**Paths:**

```
vendor/assets/stylesheets/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.css 
vendor/assets/images/jquery-ui/images/ (your theme images)
```

Read [this!](https://github.com/joliss/jquery-ui-rails)

**Answer 2:** Yes, you should be able to. Your approach seems a bit inconvenient, and I would have to see some code to help you out.

Comment: can you elaborate on your Answer 1?  I'm still confused about assets and compilation in general.  Is compilation basically the process in which different files are combined into one file for less expensive page loading?  Also, any idea why the TEST site cannot find any jquery whatsoever?  It's pretty weird that it is looking for it in /app/app/...